# How to grap all fields values from a MySQL table row in Groovy without using field names?

Tags: mysql, groovy

I'm trying to produce a flat text file from a SQL query in Groovy, with each line being the processed values of a database row, fields being separated with a customisable separator.

I successfully get all data from database query using row names and eachRow method like below.

But how could I get data without having to specify each fields, meaning iterate through query result?

Note that I need to add my custom separator between each field value and eventually process each field value if needed to do some cleaning.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

db_host = 'foo.db.int'
db_name = 'mydb'
mysql_login = 'mylogin'
mysql_password = 'XXXXXXX'

// Connection settings
def db = [
            url:'jdbc:mysql://' + db_host + ':3306/' + db_name,
            user: mysql_login,
            password:mysql_password,
            driver:'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        ]
// Create connection
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)

// Result store
def output = []

// SQL query
String sql_query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE status = 'ON'"

sql.eachRow(sql_query){ 
    // Here all field are explicitly named
    row -> output.push(row.fieldone + ';' + row.fieldtwo + ';' row.fieldthree)
}

sql.close()

// Flat file to store query result
File out_file = new File("myfile.txt")

// Populate file with result rows
output.each {
    out_file.append("$it\n")
}
```

Comment: add `println row.propertes` if you in `eachRow` closure

Comment: @injecteer: row -> prinln row.properties provoke an exception : "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:"

Comment: sorry, `i` was missing: `println row.properties`

Answer (score 0):

The following snippets may help:

```
sql.eachRow(sql_query){ row ->
    output << row.toRowResult().values()
}
...
output.each {
    out_file.append("${it.join(';')}\n")
}
```

This isn't going to be very clever if you have large amounts of data however.